# Oracle Fetch Next Row Limit by unique id's

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have a table having data as shown below,

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+
|  Id   |    TierUnitId  |  ObjectNumber  |
+-------+----------------+----------------+
|  10   |     3599       |     1          |
|  10   |     3599       |     2          |
|  20   |     3599       |     3          |
|  20   |     3599       |     4          |
|  20   |     3599       |     1          |
|  30   |     3599       |     2          |
|  30   |     3599       |     3          |
+-------+----------------+----------------+
```

I have a select query

```
SELECT ID FROM TEST
FETCH NEXT :LIMIT ROWS ONLY
```

Now I want to limit the number of rows using the value of limit.
When the value of Limit is 2 I want two distinct id's i.e up to 5 rows. However, from query I will get only two rows having 10 as the id. Can someone help me in limiting the rows using distinct id?
What i want is total number of distinct id in the output is limit.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Note that FETCH NEXT without an ORDER BY may return more or less random rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function to number the rows based on the unique/distinct `ID` values and then filter on that:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rnk
  FROM   test
)
WHERE  rnk <= 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (Id, HierUnitId, ObjectNumber ) AS
SELECT 10, 3599, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 3599, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 3599, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 3599, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 3599, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 3599, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 3599, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID |
> | --- |
> | 10 |
> | 10 |
> | 20 |
> | 20 |
> | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=32bcd5eb417c486776667c4f7988d4cb)*

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comment, you need to be able to define how many distinct ids should be shown. For that case i'd recommend you to find those ids first (see the distinct_ids part) and fetch all the lines you needed afterwards

```
with distinct_ids as (
  select distinct id
    from test_data  
   order by id
   fetch first :limit rows only)  

select id
  from test_data td
  join distinct_ids di
    on td.id = di.id
```

Comment: This won't work as limit will decide the number of distinct id. Id can have any values.I have updated my question you can look at it.

Comment: @PulkitSharma check my updated answer please

Answer (score 0):

If you need *some* distinct IDs without any particular order, then you may put `fetch next ...` into the subquery with `distinct` keyword. Index on `ID` column will be suitable to avoid two full table scans (I assume that `ID` cannot be null)

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/
>   *
> from t
> where id in (
>   select distinct id
>   from t
>   where id is not null
>   fetch next 2 rows only
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | HIERUNITID | OBJECTNUMBER
> -: | ---------: | -----------:
>  1 |       3599 |            1
>  1 |       3599 |            2
>  2 |       3599 |            3
>  2 |       3599 |            4
>  2 |       3599 |            1
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
>   format => 'ALL -PROJECTION -ALIAS ALLSTATS LAST'
> ))
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                              |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SQL_ID  2sqqq53kpy5rj, child number 0                                                                                                                          |
> | -------------------------------------                                                                                                                          |
> |  select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/   * from t where id in (   select                                                                                          |
> | distinct id   from t   where id is not null   fetch next 2 rows only )                                                                                         |
> |                                                                                                                                                                |
> | Plan hash value: 534568331                                                                                                                                     |
> |                                                                                                                                                                |
> | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation                    | Name     | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem | |
> | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |          |      1 |        |       |     5 (100)|          |      5 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          | |
> | |   1 |  MERGE JOIN SEMI             |          |      1 |      5 |   115 |     5  (40)| 00:00:01 |      5 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          | |
> | |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T        |      1 |      7 |    70 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |       |       |          | |
> | |   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | T_IX     |      1 |      7 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          | |
> | |*  4 |   SORT UNIQUE                |          |      6 |      2 |    26 |     3  (67)| 00:00:01 |      5 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)| |
> | |   5 |    VIEW                      | VW_NSO_1 |      1 |      2 |    26 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          | |
> | |*  6 |     VIEW                     |          |      1 |      2 |    20 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          | |
> | |*  7 |      WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY   |          |      1 |      3 |    39 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       1 | 73728 | 73728 |          | |
> | |   8 |       VIEW                   |          |      1 |      3 |    39 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          | |
> | |   9 |        SORT UNIQUE NOSORT    |          |      1 |      3 |     9 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          | |
> | |* 10 |         INDEX FULL SCAN      | T_IX     |      1 |      7 |    21 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          | |
> | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                                                                                |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                            |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                            |
> |                                                                                                                                                                |
> |    4 - access("ID"="ID")                                                                                                                                       |
> |        filter("ID"="ID")                                                                                                                                       |
> |    6 - filter("from$_subquery$_004"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=2)                                                                                                |
> |    7 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL)<=2)                                                                                                           |
> |   10 - filter("ID" IS NOT NULL)                                                                                                                                |
> |                                                                                                                                                                |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=abb005889ee14963359e912fccf6f027)*